# How to highlight entity references (&blah;) in atom/language-babel

Tags: atom-editor

In ST3 I had some nice package (probably JSX or something) that highlighted entity references (eg. `&nbsp;`) for me.

How can I get this back with Atom/language-babel?

I tried installing the `react` package, but then it said it conflicted with `language-babel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it looks like I wasn't using `language-babel`, I was using `language-js`, because my JSX files have the `.js` extension.

Here's how you can tell Atom to use `language-babel` for all your `.js` files: [atom how to change default syntax highlighting for .js files to language-babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53145360/atom-how-to-change-default-syntax-highlighting-for-js-files-to-language-babel)